# How to estimate eta and rho with BOBYQA for 'geopst' Radial Basis Function (rbf) in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, geospatial

According to the [CRAN documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geospt/geospt.pdf) for 'geospt'

`"eta and rho; we recommend using the parameter found by minimizing the root-mean-square prediction errors using cross-validation. eta and rho parameters can be optimized simultaneously, through the bobyqa function from nloptr or minqa packages"`

I can get `geospt::rbf()` to work nearly as desired with hard coded values for `eta` and `rho`, but I am basically just getting a flat plane fit to my data that are not at all flat. I think this has to do with these `eta` and `rho` values, but I can't figure out how to optimize them. It seems like it depends on what function you are using for the rbf. I am try inverse multiquadratic right now, but I would like to be able to optimize each type of function.

my rbf() call looks like this :

```
rbf_test<-rbf(formula=z~x+y,
      data=spatial_df,
      newdata=spatial_grid,
      eta=0.14,
      rho=0,
      func="IM",
      n.neigh =8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to determine the eta and rho values, so, following the CRAN documentary for 'geospt', you can optimize them using the function 'graph.rbf'

```
# optimizing eta
graph.rbf(prec~1, preci, eta.opt=TRUE, rho.opt=FALSE, n.neigh=9, func="TPS",
np=40, eta.dmax=0.2, P.T=TRUE)

# optimizing rho
graph.rbf(prec~x+y, preci, eta.opt=FALSE, rho.opt=TRUE, n.neigh=9, func="M",
np=20, rho.dmax=2, P.T=TRUE)
```